# Joomla - Importing sql database to new server results to error

Tags: sql, database, joomla, mariadb

I want to **move** a website built in *Joomla 3.5.1* to a new server. Bought domain/space at the new server and I backed up the database/files from the old one.

I transferred the files via ftp to the new server and I opened phpmyadmin to import the .sql file. The thing is that after it's uploaded, I get the following error:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set parent.`,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set lft.`,
  `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested set rgt.`,
  `level` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'The cached level in the nested tree.',
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The unique name for the asset.\n',
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'The descriptive title for the asset.',
  `rules` varchar(5120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'JSON encoded access control.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `Nested set parent.`,
>         `lft` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT AS `Nested ' at line 3

Tried some edits on the sql import file but with no luck. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **missing spaces** before the keyword COMMENT:

```
'0'COMMENT
```

should be

```
'0' COMMENT
```

there are three occurrences here I bet you might find more errors, which you can fix by simple find/replace (sed);

Best of all you should try and get a new backup: possibly these could have been linux line endings trimmed in a double conversion to windows and back? You might zip / gzip the sql dump on the source server and explode on the destination server, to guarantee line ending integrity; or for ftp transfer choose binary mode.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo yeah the phpmyadmin export seems to mess up with the tables.

Tried an export Dump from the Plesk Control Panel and imported it again from the new CP. Seems to be transfered without any problem now.